# jQuery Dynamic Button Click Handler

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a code the change the html of a div to make a button. When I make a click handler for the dynamic button, nothing happens

```
$('#signinup').html("<button id=\"login_submit\">Sign In</button>");
```

And the handler:

```
$('#login_submit').click(function() {
   alert("Works!");
});
```

Comment: When does the click handler code run in conjunction with the HTML generation? Also, have you tried the bind or live event handler methods?

Comment: Are you sure, you add your handler after the button is created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[See the working demo :)](http://jsbin.com/eruza3/2)**

Use the **[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method:

```
$('#login_submit').live('click', function() {
   alert("Works!");
});
```

The `live()` method attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

Comment: @joshperry: Thanks for notifying that, actually I posted a wrong working link, updated now. Thanks

Comment: "live" function is deprecated if working with new versions of jQuery just change the "live" function for the "on" function http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

`.live` doesn't work always.
Many a times it does, but recently I crashed at a situation wherein I am updating/loading the buttons dynamically which performs some action. Just like you see the **Confirm friend request** button in facebook friend requests popup flyout.